# MUD Telnet game

Tags: javascript, server, async-await, promise

I'm new in JS and my daily job is PHP, so I decided to do simple MUD Telnet game to practice my JS skills.

The idea was to use async/await to do Telnet server code that seems synchronous at first glance. I run this code with "babel-node app.js".

```
'use strict';

let Promise = require('bluebird');
let net = Promise.promisifyAll(require('net'));

// Async code ahead...
(async () => {

  // Get me some server.
  let server = net.createServer();

  // On new connection.
  server.on('connection', async (socket) => {

    // Set socket (stream) encoding on utf8.
    socket.setEncoding('utf8');

    // Say hello to the client.
    socket.write('hello\r\n');
    socket.write('waiting for input... ');

    // Await input from client
    let input = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      socket.on('data', resolve);
    }); 

    socket.write('input received: ' + input);
    console.log('input received: ' + input)
  }); 

  await server.listenAsync(1234);
  console.log('server is ready for connections');
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with the code except for the following:

```
// Await input from client
let input = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  socket.on('data', resolve);
});
```

The `data` event can fire multiple times, depending on how often the client sends in data. However, a promise can be thought of as a one-off event emitter. Once it gets resolved, *it stays resolved*. So even if the data event fires again, nothing will happen.

This also means the async `connection` event handler makes no sense, so that goes away making the bulk of  your code a traditional callback-y node script.

Async/await makes sense with one-off async operations that "return" (like network requests, fs operations, etc.). Not saying async/await is useless. This is just a bad example for async as the operation requires event emitters, not promises.